# react-native react-native-vector-icons: How to use font awesome icons

Tags: react-native, font-awesome

In my react-native application I have added this library react-native-vector-icons to use icons. From the github page, FontAwesome is listed among the bundled icon sets. But I don't see how I can reference a fontawesome item in my  element. It seems that I can only use "ios-xxx", "md-xxx" or "log-xxx".

When I try something like:

```js
<Icon name='fa-rss' style={{marginRight:10}} />
```

I get this warning:

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use

```js
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

<Icon name="rss" size={30} color="#900" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tried your code:

<Icon name='rss' icon={{ name: 'rss', type: 'font-awesome' }} style={{marginRight:10}} />, 

still same error

Answer (score 2):

Always search for the icon name here: [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/) and here: [Material-icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/) to be sure that you are using the correct name. Then simply you can use the code as:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
<Icon name="rocket" size={30} color="#900" />    // Here use the correct
 name from the first link above.
```

For more info refer [this](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a very large amount of them, and I don't want to import them all, I ended up importing each icon I need as an SVG.

- Download font awesome free package https://fontawesome.com/download
- add `react-native-svg` to your project

then paste it to your JSX file

```
import * as React from "react";

import { SvgXml, SvgProps } from 'react-native-svg'

const xml = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><path d="M470.1 231.3s7.6 37.2 9.3 45H446c3.3-8.9 16-43.5 16-43.5-.2.3 3.3-9.1 5.3-14.9l2.8 13.4zM576 80v352c0 26.5-21.5 48-48 48H48c-26.5 0-48-21.5-48-48V80c0-26.5 21.5-48 48-48h480c26.5 0 48 21.5 48 48zM152.5 331.2L215.7 176h-42.5l-39.3 106-4.3-21.5-14-71.4c-2.3-9.9-9.4-12.7-18.2-13.1H32.7l-.7 3.1c15.8 4 29.9 9.8 42.2 17.1l35.8 135h42.5zm94.4.2L272.1 176h-40.2l-25.1 155.4h40.1zm139.9-50.8c.2-17.7-10.6-31.2-33.7-42.3-14.1-7.1-22.7-11.9-22.7-19.2.2-6.6 7.3-13.4 23.1-13.4 13.1-.3 22.7 2.8 29.9 5.9l3.6 1.7 5.5-33.6c-7.9-3.1-20.5-6.6-36-6.6-39.7 0-67.6 21.2-67.8 51.4-.3 22.3 20 34.7 35.2 42.2 15.5 7.6 20.8 12.6 20.8 19.3-.2 10.4-12.6 15.2-24.1 15.2-16 0-24.6-2.5-37.7-8.3l-5.3-2.5-5.6 34.9c9.4 4.3 26.8 8.1 44.8 8.3 42.2.1 69.7-20.8 70-53zM528 331.4L495.6 176h-31.1c-9.6 0-16.9 2.8-21 12.9l-59.7 142.5H426s6.9-19.2 8.4-23.3H486c1.2 5.5 4.8 23.3 4.8 23.3H528z"/></svg>`

export const VisaIcon = (props: SvgProps) => <SvgXml xml={xml} {...props} />
```

Don't forget to pass `width`, `height` and `fill` properties to your icon.

Comment: Unless you use an icon inside your project, that will not be available in your bundle. So we need not worry about the more number of icons in the list.

Answer (score -1):

Looking in [fontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons/home?style=solid), find your icon and click and details inside the class ie:

```
<i class="fas fa-home"></i>
```

have the prop `fa-home` use `faHome` in you code without '-'.

You can try to typing and the VSCode suggest the name of icon like image below:

[image: example1]